# Use Hypermedia instead after first Level in rest URI?

Tags: rest

I am thinking that you don't have UriTemplates like this one ever:

`http://myapi.com/cage/12/pigs/23` - give me pig 23 that is in cage 12

I am thinking the standard or REST APIs don't normally tack on the /pigs/23.  I think you just keep everything to one level so if I want that pig it'd get it from the Pig service `and by sending a request to /pigs/23`

In other words you're never gonna see a url like this coming into a RESTful API:

```
http://myapi.com/cage/12/pigs/23
```

because how woudl you handle that in terms of mapping that to a specific method in the pigs service?  Would you strip out the cageId of 12 from the GetByCage(int id, int cageId) of the pigs service?

I I think that would get too complicated because I can seen then a ton of these type of BySomething methods in a given resource which could become non-consistent or unmaintainable if you think about all the resources doing this in your API.

If I am not incorrect I believe people keep it to just [resource]/[id] - one level meaning you never go beyond the initial resource or id in a Uri, you stop there.  Then in the response you use hypermedia to give the consumer another Uri to get to that other resource.

So in the case of `http://myapi.com/cage/12/pigs/23` it should really never be that.  It should be a call to /cage/12, you get that cage representation back.  Then in the cage json object you'll see a property maybe like `http://myapi.com/pigs/23` and make another call?  That's 2 calls, might be heavy instead of somehow making one call by putting sub resources into the Uri like above (pig is a subresource of cage).  So do you put sub resoure in as hypermedia (links inside the main resource) and stop there, meaning in a REST API you never go beyond the first resource you request, you don't list subresources in the url itself, but to use hypermedia instead and embed that into the first resource...right?

don't know, but I found this also:
http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

Comment: If you're going RESTful and hypermedia, then URI design should be one of the least important aspects - because outside of a few exposed URIs that callers are expected to start at, all other URIs are provided by your service in responses - so whatever they currently are, you can change your mind later and provide different ones. If cages are responsible for numbering their pigs, such that two cages have a pig 23, and those aren't the same pigs, then I think the first URI you show is perfectly fine.

Comment: the Uri is the least important as now it only gets one thing, it's dumbed down to an atomic resource on every call, so yep, hypermedia is what is driving the relationships and etc. along with filters in the querystring for stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with

```
myapi.com/cage/12/pigs/34
```

if that makes sense in the context of the resource you are returning. This is especially true if `pig 34` only makes sense in the context of `cage 12`, and is a different pig to `pig 34` in `cage 09`, then this would be the correct way to do it. It also makes sense if your client will want to query all the pigs that would be in cage 12 with the URL `myapi.com/cage/12/pigs`, which should return URLs to all the pigs in that cage.

Generally don't stress about how difficult a URL will be to parse on your server, pretty much every language you would be using for web development has libraries to help with this. Think what makes sense in relation to your resource representations.

Comment: I'm thinking about using hypermedia instead and then we won't even have to worry about urls that are complex like this.  We would only have urls to the first level, either [resource]/ (give me all of it) or [resource]/{id} and we wouldn't need anything after that.

Comment: Um you have to, it's part of the backend design and also usability as it relates to REST.  I'm not worried about just parsing, it's method naming, where the methods will lie (what controller or service) and also more importantly scalability.  Using Hypermedia is a better route than making your url overly complex.  Atomic Resources means each reasource only provides the simple cruds and that's it.  No GetByOtherId nonsense.  Hypermedia solves that problem and provides a lot of other benefits as well.

Comment: What do you mean by hypermedia _instead_? Using hypermedia won't, or shouldn't, effect your URLs. As for having having really short URLs, that is fine if it suits your resource hierarchy. In example you gave though that doesn't seem to fit. Pigs are in cages, and this is reflected in the URL. Making all the URLs short doesn't reflect this relationship. You shouldn't do this to make the code on the server easier if it means you lose semantic meaning on the client end.

Comment: then you don't understand hypermedia (Resource linking).  watch this, it will allow you to trim and not have so many complicated URls for your REST API.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5WXYw4J4QOU

Comment: I understand what hypermedia is. The fact that URLs shouldn't be hard coded into the client and should be discovered as it traverses the resources doesn't mean that resource hierarchies are irrelevant once the client is actually doing this. For example if your URL was api.com/cages/12 linking to api.com/pigs/45 when the client gets to pig 45 how does it get back to cage 12? You either have to tell the client to remember the URL it was previously at (how?), or embed the url for the cage in the pig resource. If the URL was api.com/cage/12/pigs/45 the client simply follows the URL backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my own solution.  That is to use Hypermedia as a means to manage Resource Linking (relationships) rather than deal with and have your users deal with longer complicated URIs.

Anyway, watch this and you will understand, he puts it perfectly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5WXYw4J4QOU

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Links die and videos aren't something that can just be skimmed.